# Cognos SDK. Get data from data source

Tags: sdk, cognos

I'm trying to use Cognos as web service with Cognos SDK. Some controls in the reports uses data from a datasource to display combobox items. I should make such controls at the client side but don't know how to get data from datasource with Cognos SDK.

My question is how to get some data from Cognos datasource using Cognos SDK.